# Geospatial Projects Management System/Software for multiple concurrent Projects

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for a System/Software for managing multiple (20+) Academic Researches and Projects.

Due to a large number of active projects lately, which many of consist of the same geographical location, we are in need of a System/Software that has mainly the following features:

- Important Feature: Attribute of projects geographical location (e.g. Search for projects in a specific location)
- Common Features: Deadline / Done - To Do / Project Personnel Information
- Being able to gather each project files in one location and accessible from everywhere (Cloud? Add-on for cloud?).
- Being able to set priorities for projects.
- Bonus: After setting the system up, needs as little maintenance as possible.

Any suggestions for such a software/system would be great. Ideas and advises are welcomed.

Comment: Redmine is a bugtracker which probably meets most, if not all of your requirements

Comment: What should each project contain, except from task tracking? Do you need a calendar, a Gantt chart, a documents library, a wiki, etc?